# Accessing Nested objects in typeScript using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

I have a json file which contains json objects like following .

```
 {
  "RegionNames" : ["Region1", "Region2"],
  "StageNames" : ["Stage1", "Stage2"],
  "stages" : {
     "Stage1" : {
         "Region1" : {
            "var1": "value1",
            "var2": "value2"  
         },
         "Region2" : {
            "var1": "value1",
            "var2": "value2"
         }
      },
     "Stage2" : {
         "Region2" : {
            "var1": "value1";,
            "var2": "value2";
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to access this variable the var1 & var2 of both Region1 & Region2 in each stage .

//How i've tried accessing them in another typeScript file , the above content is in jsonContent.json : -

```
const stages =jsonContent.StageNames;
const regions = jsonContent.RegionNames;

for (let stageIndex in stages) {
    for (let regionIndex in regions) {
        console.log("Variable1 value :"+ jsonContent.stages[stageIndex].regions[regionIndex].var1)
        console.log("Variable2 value :"+
jsonContent.stages[stageIndex].regions[regionIndex].var2)
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me in this accessing in json using loop .

I need to use "RegionNames" & "StageNames" variables to run that loop , but not able to do so .
Can someone please help .

Comment: `let var = {` means that it's not JSON. It also has syntax errors.

Comment: yeah , now removed it . Can you pin point other errors , if any .

Comment: May you also please update the question to include a [mcve] of how you have tried accessing the properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` method on any object and convert it into array then use loops to access props and it's value ... Moreover I had to use `forEach` loop since your object isn't ideal ( meant to say that it contains something like item1 not item)..

```
let jsonContent = {
  "RegionNames": ["Region1",
    "Region2"],
  "StageNames": ["Stage1",
    "Stage2"],
  "stages": {
    "Stage1": {
      "Region1": {
        "var1": "value1",
        "var2": "value2"
      }
    },
    "Stage2": {
      "Region2": {
        "var1": "value1",
        "var2": "value2"
      }
    }
  }
};

const array = [];
Object.entries(jsonContent.stages).forEach(entry=> array.push(entry[1]));
array.forEach((item, index)=>{
    index++;
    const region = 'Region'+ index;
    const object = item[region];
    // console.log(object)
    console.log("Variable1 value :"+ object.var1);
    console.log("Variable2 value :"+ object.var2);
});
```

> Note : you should never use indexes inside object like item1 as in objects of same data structure it is recommended to  store data in easy way not using  indexes with....

Comment: @Shivanshu btw you should never write object with indexes ! Eg. `Region1` could have been written as `Region` only ...

Comment: can you please elaborate this item & index thing that you used in loop .

Comment: @Shivanshu Okay I got it ! I used forEach loop a method in `array` by which we can loop through each item present in an array ..(see  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more info about it  )...... The INDEX is the index of the item ( in array ) and the item is the thing present in the array

Comment: thanks , Got it . but this is throwing compile time error due to arrayType is any[] .
As arrayType is nested , how can we provide it an appropriate type .